# What is mysql query to fetch 99 th record in Table?

Tags: mysql

Suppose we have table name called "Person" having some column name Like `"Firstname","LastName","OrderId"`.

Table has 100 rows in DB,I want to fetch 99 th row from the Table Person.

Kindly give mysql query.

Thanks in advance,

Dinesh Kumar Manoharan

Comment: 99th row if you sort the table in **What order**  ?

Answer (score 5):

Try this -

```
select * from Person limit 98,1
```

If you want to order by,

```
select * from Person order by columnName limit 98,1
```

Comment: Rows are zero indexed, so to target the 99th row, use 98, not 99.

Comment: @Grim - When I posted my answer, I saw your answer too and almost intantly your edit too. Thats when I realized my answer was wrong. But before I could edit, @Rob had already pointed that in comment.. Sure SO has some very fast users ;) and happy to take all help too :)

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT * FROM Person LIMIT 98, 1
```

First row is 0.

Make sure to order it by something.

Comment: I'm simply amazed of how a "correct" answer to an ill-defined question gets 2 votes and an OK by the OP.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no guarantee that `SELECT * FROM aTable` will return rows always in same order. It usually does return rows in the order they were inserted in the database. But are you sure that this is always true, for all versions of MySQL, all engines, all types of (clustered or not) indexes used, whether the table is partitioned or not, etc?

Comment: I agree, but OP didn't mention order. It's a valid point, so I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you wish to order them by OrderId:

```
SELECT * FROM Person ORDER BY OrderId LIMIT 1 OFFSET 98
```

Comment: LIMIT with 2 arguments is functionally identical to defining LIMIT and OFFSET explicitly